# ajax'ом не загружается контент

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

Есть инициализация ajax, с помощью которого загружается контент по клику на пункты меню хэдера и футера (оба статичны). Между ними есть контейнер, куда идет загрузка. Контент загружается, но.. один момент, необходимо загружать странички по клику на пункты меню, которые находятся непосредственно в самом загруженном контенте. Т.е. загрузилась страничка - на этой страничке есть доп. меню с тегами a. Href прописаны, но при клике просто загружается страница отдельным бланком (вкладкой).

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.main_menu a, .footer_submenu a, .simple_text_content a').on('click', function(event) {

        //event.preventDefault();
        
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: $(this).attr('href'),
            cache: false,
            isLocal: true,
            success: function(html){
                $('.main_content_container').html(html);
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 100);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '.main_menu a, .footer_submenu a, .simple_text_content a', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  ...
```

Comment: так работает. Спасибо!